# how to get the intermediate layer output of the resnet which creates by keras in tensorflow2.0, I want to use resnet as a image feature extractor

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0, feature-extraction

residual_block.py

```
import tensorflow as tf


class BasicBlock(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self, filter_num, stride=1):
        super(BasicBlock, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=filter_num,
                                            kernel_size=(3, 3),
                                            strides=stride,
                                            padding="same")
        self.bn1 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()
        self.conv2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=filter_num,
                                            kernel_size=(3, 3),
                                            strides=1,
                                            padding="same")
        self.bn2 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()
        if stride != 1:
            self.downsample = tf.keras.Sequential()
            self.downsample.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=filter_num,
                                                       kernel_size=(1, 1),
                                                       strides=stride))
            self.downsample.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
        else:
            self.downsample = lambda x: x

    def call(self, inputs, training=None, **kwargs):
        residual = self.downsample(inputs)

        x = self.conv1(inputs)
        x = self.bn1(x, training=training)
        x = tf.nn.relu(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.bn2(x, training=training)

        output = tf.nn.relu(tf.keras.layers.add([residual, x]))

        return output


class BottleNeck(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, filter_num, stride=1):
        super(BottleNeck, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=filter_num,
                                            kernel_size=(1, 1),
                                            strides=1,
                                            padding='same')
        self.bn1 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()
        self.conv2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=filter_num,
                                            kernel_size=(3, 3),
                                            strides=stride,
                                            padding='same')
        self.bn2 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()
        self.conv3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=filter_num * 4,
                                            kernel_size=(1, 1),
                                            strides=1,
                                            padding='same')
        self.bn3 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()

        self.downsample = tf.keras.Sequential()
        self.downsample.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=filter_num * 4,
                                                   kernel_size=(1, 1),
                                                   strides=stride))
        self.downsample.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())

    def call(self, inputs, training=None, **kwargs):
        residual = self.downsample(inputs)

        x = self.conv1(inputs)
        x = self.bn1(x, training=training)
        x = tf.nn.relu(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.bn2(x, training=training)
        x = tf.nn.relu(x)
        x = self.conv3(x)
        x = self.bn3(x, training=training)

        output = tf.nn.relu(tf.keras.layers.add([residual, x]))

        return output


def make_basic_block_layer(filter_num, blocks, stride=1):
    res_block = tf.keras.Sequential()
    res_block.add(BasicBlock(filter_num, stride=stride))

    for _ in range(1, blocks):
        res_block.add(BasicBlock(filter_num, stride=1))

    return res_block


def make_bottleneck_layer(filter_num, blocks, stride=1):
    res_block = tf.keras.Sequential()
    res_block.add(BottleNeck(filter_num, stride=stride))

    for _ in range(1, blocks):
        res_block.add(BottleNeck(filter_num, stride=1))

    return res_block
```

resnet.py

```
import tensorflow as tf
from config import NUM_CLASSES
from models.residual_block import make_basic_block_layer, make_bottleneck_layer


class ResNetTypeI(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, layer_params):
        super(ResNetTypeI, self).__init__()

        self.conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64,
                                            #kernel_size=(7, 7),
                                            kernel_size=(3, 3),
                                            # strides=2,
                                            strides=1,
                                            padding="same")
        self.bn1 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()
        # self.pool1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3, 3),
        #                                        strides=2,
        #                                        padding="same")
        self.pool1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2),
                                            strides=1,
                                            padding="same")
        self.layer1 = make_basic_block_layer(filter_num=64,
                                             blocks=layer_params[0])
        self.layer2 = make_basic_block_layer(filter_num=128,
                                             blocks=layer_params[1],
                                             stride=2)
        self.layer3 = make_basic_block_layer(filter_num=256,
                                             blocks=layer_params[2],
                                             stride=2)
        self.layer4 = make_basic_block_layer(filter_num=512,
                                             blocks=layer_params[3],
                                             stride=2)

        self.avgpool = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
        self.fc = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=NUM_CLASSES, activation=tf.keras.activations.softmax)

    def call(self, inputs, training=None, mask=None):

        x = self.conv1(inputs)
        x = self.bn1(x, training=training)
        x = tf.nn.relu(x)
        x = self.pool1(x)
        x = self.layer1(x, training=training)
        x = self.layer2(x, training=training)
        x = self.layer3(x, training=training)
        x = self.layer4(x, training=training)
        x = self.avgpool(x)

        output = self.fc(x)


        return output


class ResNetTypeII(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, layer_params):
        super(ResNetTypeII, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64,
                                            kernel_size=(7, 7),
                                            strides=2,
                                            padding="same")
        self.bn1 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()
        self.pool1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3, 3),
                                               strides=2,
                                               padding="same")

        self.layer1 = make_bottleneck_layer(filter_num=64,
                                            blocks=layer_params[0])
        self.layer2 = make_bottleneck_layer(filter_num=128,
                                            blocks=layer_params[1],
                                            stride=2)
        self.layer3 = make_bottleneck_layer(filter_num=256,
                                            blocks=layer_params[2],
                                            stride=2)
        self.layer4 = make_bottleneck_layer(filter_num=512,
                                            blocks=layer_params[3],
                                            stride=2)

        self.avgpool = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
        self.fc = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=NUM_CLASSES, activation=tf.keras.activations.softmax)

    def call(self, inputs, training=None, mask=None):
        x = self.conv1(inputs)
        x = self.bn1(x, training=training)
        x = tf.nn.relu(x)
        x = self.pool1(x)
        x = self.layer1(x, training=training)
        x = self.layer2(x, training=training)
        x = self.layer3(x, training=training)
        x = self.layer4(x, training=training)
        x = self.avgpool(x)
        output = self.fc(x)

        return output


def resnet_18():
    return ResNetTypeI(layer_params=[2, 2, 2, 2])


def resnet_34():
    return ResNetTypeI(layer_params=[3, 4, 6, 3])


def resnet_50():
    return ResNetTypeII(layer_params=[3, 4, 6, 3])


def resnet_101():
    return ResNetTypeII(layer_params=[3, 4, 23, 3])


def resnet_152():
    return ResNetTypeII(layer_params=[3, 8, 36, 3])
```

The resnet model has no problem, I can use it to train and predict, but I want to get the intermediate layers output of resnet to create a image feature extractor, it doesn't work.

the main.py

```
from ResNet.models import resnet
import tensorflow as tf
import config

res34 = resnet.resnet_34()
res34.build(input_shape=(None, config.image_height, config.image_width, config.channels))
res34.load_weights('./ResNet/saved_model/model')

res34.summary()
sub_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=res34.input, outputs=res34.layers[-2].output)
sub_model.summary()
```

Traceback info:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/Desktop/statsInfoRMHC/subModel.py", line 26, in 
sub_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=res34.input, outputs=res34.layers[-2].output)
File "C:\Users\longj\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 1576, in output
raise AttributeError('Layer ' + self.name + ' has no inbound nodes.')
AttributeError: Layer global_average_pooling2d has no inbound nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to...

## Extend ResNetTypeI with new def

Create a new def in your class ResNetTypeI

```
def features(self,inputs):
    x = self.conv1(inputs)
    x = self.bn1(x, training=training)
    x = tf.nn.relu(x)
    x = self.pool1(x)
    x = self.layer1(x, training=training)
    x = self.layer2(x, training=training)
    x = self.layer3(x, training=training)
    x = self.layer4(x, training=training)
    return self.avgpool(x)
```

This function will allow you to extract the subgraph.  Now later in the program use it instead of `sub_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=res34.input, outputs=res34.layers[-2].output)` , so the last lines of your code would now be

```
res34.summary()
sub_model_input = tf.layers.Input( ... )
sub_model_output = res34.features(sub_model_input)
sub_model = tf.keras.Model(sub_model_input,sub_model_output)
sub_model.summary()
```

That is totally hack, which is why I suggest

## Reduce ResNetTypeI to only return the features

Instead of doing all the above, instead just remove the last layer for your resnet models so it just returns features.  "WHAT?" you say, "what about my classification?".  No problem, look at this handy wrapper

```
def addClassificationToModel(feature_model):
    classification_output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=NUM_CLASSES, activation=tf.keras.activations.softmax)(feature_model.output)
    return tf.keras.Model(feature_model.input,classification_output)
```

which turns any feature model into a classification model.  When you train the classification model, it also trains the underlying feature model.  This is really nice and reusable.  Much more slick than the above and/or trying to pull the feature model out of the classification model.